# How to trigger ionViewWillLeave in Ionic 4 with route in tabs.router.module

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, angular-lifecycle-hooks

Lifecycle hooks `ionViewWillLeave` / `ionViewDidLeave` are not triggered when placing all pages routes in TabsPageRoutingModule.

We changed the routes from `app-routing.module.ts` to `tabs.router.module.ts` to get full view of the tabbar in the Ionic 4 app. The routes works perfectly.
When the routes were in `app-routing.module.ts`, the `ionViewWillLeave` was always triggered when leaving the page (and closing the present `Observables`). Now the `ionViewWillLeave` is not triggered when leaving the page.

**Route in tabs.router.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'tabs',
    component: TabsPage,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/tabs/(home:home)',
        pathMatch: 'full',
      },
      {
        path: 'home',
        outlet: 'home',
        component: HomePage
      },
      {
        path: 'chats',
        outlet: 'chats',
        component: ChatsPage
      },
...
```

**Logging failed for ionViewWillLeave in TS file**

```
ionViewWillEnter() {
  console.log('ionViewWillEnter');  // <- In console when entering
}
ionViewWillLeave() {
  console.log('ionViewWillLeave');  // <- Not in console when leaving
}
```

Can't figure out why the `ionViewWillLeave` is not printed anymore. Any help is appreciated.

---

**Route in app-routing.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', loadChildren: './tabs/tabs.module#TabsPageModule' },
  { path: 'chats', loadChildren: './chats.module#ChatsPageModule' },
...
```

**Logging success for ionViewWillLeave in TS file**

```
ionViewWillEnter() {
  console.log('ionViewWillEnter');  // <- In console when entering
}
ionViewWillLeave() {
  console.log('ionViewWillLeave');  // <- In console when leaving
}
```

Comment: Is ionViewWillLeave / ionViewDidLeave are getting triggered?

Comment: found a solution for this?

Comment: @Jonathan my problem was solved when I applied the breaking changes for that particular build. Are you facing similar issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution for our problem

**Breaking changes to tabs**
[4.0.0-beta.18 (2018-12-13)](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#400-beta18-2018-12-13)

Stopped using outlet/component in tab-router, now we directly place children pages in the tabbed path.

```
{
  path: 'tabs',
  component: TabsPage,
  children: [
    {
      path: 'home',
      children: [
        {
          path: '',
          loadChildren: '../home/home.module#HomePageModule'
        },
        {
          path: 'chats'
          children: [
          {
            path: '',
            loadChildren: '../chats/chats.module#ChatsPageModule'
          }
        ]
      },
...
```